# What is the fastest build-order to get Reavers in Starcraft Broodwar?

Tags: starcraft-protoss, starcraft

I love watching *Gojilla* play Reavers.

What is the fastest build-order to get Reaver units in Starcraft Broodwar?

Comment: Are you asking in a sense where you don't get any other units early on and just go straight for a Reaver? (Which you'll probably lose to if scouted).

Comment: @Sorean Of course we should never go solely for reaver. We always need some Zealot and Dragon with reaver - the question is how to create such army the most quickly way?

Comment: Which match-ups are you interested in? You can go reavers in all 3, not just PvT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the best all around fast reaver build that keeps you safe.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/1_Gate_Reaver

Also, stackexchange isn't really meant to be a discussion board, more of a Q&A thing here. If you want discussions you are better off at [TeamLiquid](http://www.teamliquid.net) or the [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/) sub-reddit.

Comment: Just like the build you found on Liquipedia, there are well-defined  reaver builds. Maybe we can edit the question to sound less subjective. Just like he stated in his comment, he's not looking to cut units or probes, so he doesn't want the "fastest" reaver rush build.